# web_crawling/scraping_Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, categories

I have found here a question and answer about web scraping with python, through all categories and subcategories, [Python web scraping - Loop through all categories and subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567368/python-web-scraping-loop-through-all-categories-and-subcategories). I have tried to modify (Topto) code with this site: https://gepborzeszeged.hu/ but code doesn't error, and it doesn't work. The goal was to gather information of products (categories, names, prices). 
But it got deleted because it does not provide solution to the OP's question. So, I don't know where is a problem.

try_1.py

`import requests`

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

`res = requests.get('https://gepborzeszeged.hu/')`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")`

`enfor items in soup.select("#menu_menu"):
    page = requests.get(items['href'])
    broth = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")`

    `for links in broth.select("#productsOfCategory .product"):
        req = requests.get(links['href'])
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")`

```
    for data in sauce.select(".product"):
        title = data.select('href')[0].text
        price = ' '.join([item.text for item in data.select(".listingPrice span")])
        print(title.strip(),price.strip())
```

also tried this, doesn't work:

try_2.py

```
from lxml import html
```

`import requests
import time`

`class AppCrawler:`

```
def __init__(self, starting_url, depth):
    self.starting_url = starting_url
    self.depth = depth
    self.current_depth = 0
    self.depth_links = []
    self.apps = []

def crawl(self):
    app = self.get_app_from_link(self.starting_url)
    self.apps.append(app)
    self.depth_links.append(app.links)

    while self.surrent_depth < self.depth:
        current_links = []
        for link in self.depth_links[self.current_depth]:
            current_app = self.get_app_from_link(link)
            current_links.extend(current_app.links)
            self.apps.append(current_app)
            time.sleep(5)
        self.apps.append(current_app)
        self.depth_links.append(current_links)

def get_app_from_link(self, link):
    start_page = requests.get(link)
    tree = html.fromstring(start_page.text)

    name = tree.xpath('//div[@class="listingProductName"]/text()')[0]
    developer = tree.xpath('//div[@class="listingAttr"]//text()')[0]
    price = tree.xpath('//span[@class="nowrap"]/text()')[0]
    links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="product "]//*/a/()')[0]

    app = App(name, developer, price, links)

    return app
```

`class App:`

```
def __init__(self, name, developer, price, links):
    self.name = name
    self.developer = developer
    self.price = price
    self.links = links

def __str__(self):
    return ("Name: " + self.name.encode('UTF-8') +
    "\r\nDeveloper: " + self.developer.encode('UTF-8') +
    "\r\nPrice: " + self.price.encode('UTF-8') + "\r\n")
```

`crawler = AppCrawler("https://gepborzeszeged.hu/", 1)
crawler.crawl()`

`for app in crawler.apps:
    print app`

Does anyone have a solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: do you have error or something?

Comment: first code I don't, but it doesn't do anything. 
second code, problem is `self.depth_links.append(app.links)`, so i think here is a problem: 
`links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="product "]//*/a/()')[0]`

but what?

Comment: hmm, the site seems to be unreachable so can never really see the response object